# node.js static files getting http 303

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I've reviewed related posts but didn't find an answer for my problem:

1. my static content located under `public/css` `public/js` and `public/img`
2. my server.js has following entry:

   `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
3. this is how I refer to static files:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
   `<script src="/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>`
   `<script src="/js/angular/apps.js"></script>`
   `<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`
   `<script src="/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>`
4. When I run node.js locally on Windows machine everything is just fine, but after deployment to linux machine I'm getting HTTP 303 on every call to static file.

Comment: What is the `Location` header value on the response?

Comment: for http://<host>:3000/css/bootstrap.min.css request , the Location response is /css/bootstrap.min.css/

Comment: Not sure what the fix is, but for some reason it thinks `/css/bootstrap.min.css` is a directory rather than a file, that's why it's doing a 303 redirect...

Comment: Matt, thanks for your comment. Just checked FS and indeed all files recognized as directories.